# SQL Condition with multiple value, return item has to have all of the value

Tags: mysql

I need an sql query condition that will meet the requirement. Example Table

```
ID FieldA FieldB
1  A      Cat
2  A      Dog
3  A      Horse
4  B      Dog
5  B      Horse
6  B      Cat
8  C      Dog
9  C      Horse
```

So example i want to get FieldA that contain in FieldB Dog,Horse using IN condition should return

```
FieldA
A
B
C
```

But if i want Dog,Horse,Cat it will return

```
FieldA
A
B
`C` should not be return *explained below*
```

I want the condition to exclude items that doesn't have "ALL" the condition item.
I tried looking around, the closest i can get is

```
Select FieldA
From ATable
Where 1=1 And FieldB IN (Dog,Horse,Cat) //This is numeric value *explain below*
GROUP BY FieldA
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FieldB ) > 1
```

This is a intermediate table, so the Dog,Horse,Cat is actually the Numeric ID from other table. I adjusted it just so you can understand my problem easier.

But this will still return FieldA C, which is not what i want. but only return A,B from FieldA, because both contains "ALL" the condition.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=15f0ea61bd4bf35730c3b2904905c143)**

```
Select FieldA
From ATable
Where FieldB IN ('Dog','Horse','Cat') 
GROUP BY FieldA
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FieldB )=3
```

OUTPUT:

```
FieldA
A
B
```

Comment: So the 3 means by the numbers of condition that i will be searching? since the table is a simple version, and there are chances the IN() will have more and more condition. Example if i add in IN(Dog,Horse,Cat,Pig) The Having = 4?

Comment: @SilvarCraw, yes

Comment: That Really helped out, Thanks. i was too focus on the IN() part, that clarify the part now.

Answer (score 0):

Long way around!!

```
Select FieldA, 
       group_concat(FieldB) as b
From ATable
Where FieldB IN ('Dog','Horse','Cat') 
GROUP BY FieldA
HAVING b like '%Dog%' and b like '%Horse%' and b like '%Cat%'
```